# Magnetic Transition Pymatgen Error

Tags: magnetism, pymatgen, anti-ferromagnetic

I am trying to simulate the change in magnetic moments during a ferromagnetic to antiferromagnetic transition.

```py
MagneticStructureEnumerator(SmFeO3_Mn_prop,
           default_magmoms={"Sm3+":0.009 ,"Fe3+":4.36 ,"Mn3+":5.0 ,"O2-":0.173},
           strategies=('ferromagnetic', 'antiferromagnetic'))
```

where `SmFeO3_Mn_prop` is $\ce{SmFeO3}$ ([mp-20243](https://materialsproject.org/materials/mp-24989/) in the Materials Project database) doped with $\ce{Mn}$ replacing $2$ $\ce{Fe}$ atoms.

However when I apply the `MagneticStructureEnumerator` class it returns the message: `<pymatgen.analysis.magnetism.analyzer.MagneticStructureEnumerator object at 0x7ff411d6da10>`

How may I print the generated enumerator?

Comment: I have made some edits to your question to remove/clarify some things, keep in mind stack exchange tends to be more direct than an informal email to someone.  There is no need to be too formal, but questions that get right to the point tend to get better answers.  Good first question though!

Comment: I added your comments to Tristan into the question. In the future, you can edit your question add additional information rather than using comments. This makes it easier to find and can have improved formatting.

Comment: @TristanMaxson Thanks for helping out here. I noticed the original version needed a bit of polishing, so I asked Tyberius to make some edits, since I was on a phone (not keyboard) while waiting at the cardiologist's office. It seems you got to it before he did, which is great.

Answer (score 6):

Oddly, despite the name, the class doesn't specifically implement any methods to do iteration directly on the object to access the structures. You can see in the [source code](https://github.com/materialsproject/pymatgen/blob/v2022.0.9/pymatgen/analysis/magnetism/analyzer.py#L625-L1103), you can see the class doesn't have an `__iter__` or `__getitem__` method.

However, it does have attributes `ordered_structures` and `ordered_structures_origin`, which are lists of structures and the transformations used to create them respectively.

So with your enumerator, you should be able to print them with:
`print(your_enum.ordered_structures)` or

```
for struct in your_enum.ordered_structures:
    print(struct)
```

I wasn't able to find the attributes of the `MagneticStructureEnumerator` object in the pymatgen documentation, so figuring out certain features may require looking at the source code until the documentation for some of these objects is more fleshed out (or I may have just missed where these attributes were described).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  However, this should really be fixed given the name.   I will bring this question up to the pymatgen people.

Comment: @TristanMaxson Yeah I had assumed your answer would work based on the name. It would presumably be a pretty simple "quality of life" addition to the code.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect this is not an error, but just an issue with how you are trying to print it.  The enumerator object is an object, so when you print it attempts to give you information about the enumerator and not the actually enumeration.  You can try to convert it to a list first, then print the enumeration.

This still might be difficult however to read, so you might try printing each magnetic structure independently and not all at once.

```
print(list(EnumeratorOfSomeData))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response ,however on doing so I am getting the error 'MagneticStructureEnumerator' object is not iterable

Comment: @k2_2009 Can you provide an example input?